# Maven log4j configuration under IntelliJ Idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, log4j

I want to configure Maven's logging under IntelliJ 14.0.3. 
I am using Maven 3.2.3. After reading [a Maven Logging 3.1.x](https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html) I configured log4j2 to highlight console output. This is the configuration:

```
<configuration>
<properties>
 <property name="maven.logging.root.level">INFO</property>
</properties>
<appenders>
<Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{[%p{WARN=WARNING}]} %msg%n%throwable" />
</Console>
</appenders>
<loggers>
<root level="${sys:maven.logging.root.level}">
  <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</root>
</loggers>
</configuration>
```

When I run it under cmd everything is ok.

[image]

IntelliJ unfortunately ignores `log4j` settings regarding the PatternLayout. Maybe am using the wrong appender?!

Comment: Stupid question - have you restarted IntelliJ IDEA? I had a similar problem when changing the default logging for a different type of Java app.

Comment: @Trisha Why is the question stupid? Yes, I have restarted IntelliJ, still no coloring of the output. There is strange symbols around the log levels `[32m[INFO][m`

Comment: Just to clarify - I meant *my* question was stupid, I assumed you had already tried a restart as the first thing

Comment: Yes. I have restarted. @Trisha did you come across to such problems before?

Comment: Yes, I have, but not using maven. And I don't know what fixed it, I found it was fixed when I came back to the code some time later, which is why I suggested the restart.